# Google API v3 OAuth2 SpreadsheedService Parsing failed error

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I want to write individual cells in Google Sheets. I'm using the new API (v3) and OAuth2 to authenticate. I authorize and authenticate using my JSON key file. I build the SpreadsheetService, then I create a query and then a feed. When creating the feed I get a `"Parsing failed (root element missing)"` error. I read the whole documentation in developers.google.com and other posts and solutions, however I seem to be missing a key element. To me looks like I can't "pass" my authentication to the Spreadsheetservice. Here is my code:

```css
        static string[] SCOPES = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
        static string APP_NAME = "Excel2Sheets";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /authentication using JSON file
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("path_to_my_fyle",
                    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    SCOPES,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Creds save to: {0}", credPath);
            }

            //building Drive Service
            var driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = APP_NAME,
            });

            SpreadsheetsService sheetService = new SpreadsheetsService("Excel2Sheets");

            SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery();
            SpreadsheetFeed feed = sheetService.Query(query);
```

Earlier, I could do it correctly but then I had trouble with the refresh token and its timeout, using API v2. That`s why I switched to v3.

Comment: V3 is the older "GData" API. If writing something new, you should use v4 as documented at https://developers.google.com/sheets/.  I don't think v2 is even available anywhere.